# Why don't my attempts to change background color work?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of the background. However, the background stays white even if I remove the background-color keeps showing me that the background color is white. To make sure that I'm changing the background I opened the style file in the browser but it still shows "background-color: white".

My code:

```
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

After adding a background:

```
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #000;
}
```

The code the browser shows:

```
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: white;
}
```

Can someone explain why is this happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the browsers cache. If the file has the same name as before the browser doesn't download the new version.

Comment: 1. Please post your code as text, NOT image.
2. Try force refresh/reload with CTRL+F5.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Is this better? @StephenOstermiller

Comment: You still need to remove the image.

Answer (score 3):

Try applying the background-color to the body, and not to the * (Universal Selector). The Universal Selector will apply the background-color to every element on the page, which might be breaking things.

If that doesn't work, make sure the css is linked to the HTML properly.

### Example of applying background-color to the body

```
body {
background-color: #333;
}
/* The above css applies a dark gray background color to the body */
```

If all of the above doesn't work, add your HTML and CSS so I can help further diagnose the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Thank you so much the problem was all about the cache of the browser I cleared it and now everything is working pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

It should provide the `background-color:#000` as you have written. There is no problem in that. Try to write the same as in the `<head>...</head>` section. So that you confirm, whether the issue is not due to some external-css file you are adding.

Also, this issue seems awkward, as I too tried and the browser is able to map correctly whatever is written in the CSS file.

It doesn't matter if you are taking `*` selector or any other selector. It doesn't make sense, nor does it affect or overrides your CSS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is awkward and this was the first time I face something like this. However, this problem was caused by the browser cache as it didn't update the css external file because it cached the old one. But, after clearing my browser cache everything went back to normal.

Comment: @salluc1 - Pl accept as answer if this helped.